# How to solve problem of timezone in Node js and mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, momentjs

I'm trying to insert start and end time like entry and exit time logic into Mongodb from node js.
My local system's timezone is IST. +5:30 offset for both client and sever.

So now follow this example.

```
entryDate: 15-10-2018, 
start: 15-10-2018 01:00:00,
end: 15-10-2018 05:00:00
```

Now since i'm on same timezone on client and server, it won't change my date value and create new object.

Then i'm storing this data into MongoDB. As you know that mongo db will convert date to UTC and then stores it. So in my DB it will look like this.

```
entryDate: ISODate("2018-10-15T00:00:00Z"), 
start: ISODate("2018-10-14T19:30:26Z"),
end: ISODate("2018-10-14T23:30:26Z")
```

So now if I want to search a query that should give me records for dates and time between 15 to 16 let's say then i won't get any data.

Now consider this case. I moved app on to the server. Now servers timezone is in UTC. So every date I pass will be converted directly in UTC so it'll insert same data like before.

Now difference here is when i want to search date range in IST timezone then it will give me the exact date to search like (15-10-2018 00:00:00) to (16-10-2018 00:00:00).

Where on server it will convert this date to UTC and can give me one day less or may be higer time like (14-10-2018 18:30:00) to (15-10-2018 18:30:00). So from the start my query is wrong.

So how to solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: use utc for all your time in server and db, convert to +5:30 for display

Comment: Ya. But problem here is when i pass date let's say 2018-01-10, it converts in server to 2018-01-09.

Comment: It should be fine since your query will also convert to 2018-01-09

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some research. I have a solution.

1. Get your date on the client side.
2. Convert that date to UTC date and pass date string to the server. Like 01-01-2018 10:00:00. (Note: we are just converting date, not the timezone)
3. On the server side create a date object from the provided date that will convert the date to UTC by default with that same time.
4. Store the date on the server side with MongoDB. Since the date is in UTC it won't convert the date again and store it as it is.
5. Now from the server, you will get the date in UTC format which will be like '2018-01-01 10:00:00'.
6. Now on the client side, create a date object from this date. This will convert your date to actual date that you passed.

This solved my problem.